# Вывести контент за пределы скролящегося родителя

Tags: html, css, css3

Возможно вытащить стрелки за пределы вертикального скролла, а горизонтальный убрать??

```css
.bg {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table
}

.col-xs-6 {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none !important;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

li {
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
}

li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: -20px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="bg">
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
          <li>Cum, corporis.</li>
          <li>Illum, ad.</li>
          <li>Eaque, consectetur.</li>
          <li>Culpa, a.</li>
          <li>Nulla, aliquid?</li>
          <li>Est, velit?</li>
          <li>Unde, autem.</li>
          <li>Ullam, ad!</li>
          <li>A, harum.</li>
          <li>Esse, dolores.</li>
          <li>Tempore, adipisci.</li>
          <li>Maiores, voluptatum.</li>
          <li>Nisi, iusto.</li>
          <li>Numquam, totam!</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ipsum odio nesciunt, pariatur aliquid laudantium consequatur odit ducimus tenetur soluta dolores harum mollitia eaque tempore blanditiis facere eveniet neque distinctio.</div>
      <div>Quia architecto laborum excepturi reiciendis vero, ab amet, voluptatibus molestiae sit earum exercitationem minima vitae! Debitis dolorem praesentium cum nam similique architecto illum magnam labore rerum assumenda soluta, unde quas.</div>
      <div>Tempore, veritatis. Sunt, accusantium, culpa quibusdam, eius enim molestiae hic blanditiis perferendis necessitatibus pariatur fugit! Inventore ad labore quae, minima cupiditate temporibus quia, debitis delectus repellat, voluptatibus reprehenderit
        laboriosam facere.</div>
      <div>Itaque molestias, quisquam ex fugiat aperiam porro sit repudiandae accusamus quod eligendi reprehenderit. Quas expedita libero quos iusto excepturi ipsum adipisci voluptatem incidunt cumque. Optio ab perspiciatis deleniti consectetur, quis?</div>
      <div>Voluptatum, quia numquam rerum saepe maxime! Quibusdam harum eveniet beatae fuga a, maxime eum sint dolorum rerum corporis qui distinctio necessitatibus cumque facilis inventore impedit totam minus temporibus officia voluptatibus.</div>
      <div>Incidunt rerum alias iusto temporibus amet illum quia aspernatur quaerat nemo veniam ipsam, natus ullam qui. Quibusdam accusantium, in explicabo nam consectetur blanditiis assumenda, facere, nobis deserunt ex omnis distinctio?</div>
      <div>Harum asperiores dolores, optio quasi hic facere quibusdam excepturi sint, natus tempore iure adipisci ab. Iste aperiam libero voluptatum, ab eos a, minus aspernatur deserunt, deleniti sunt magni in alias.</div>
      <div>Iusto fuga reprehenderit quae nihil, distinctio quam rerum tempore rem enim assumenda harum nisi consectetur, non aut nesciunt explicabo nam, architecto, nobis perferendis culpa magnam? Dolorem sequi quod, temporibus tempora.</div>
      <div>Sapiente, esse adipisci voluptates non porro dolorum libero dolores, ipsam consequuntur quaerat ea optio illum sint, dignissimos sunt soluta. Accusantium consequatur, minima modi quasi quaerat reiciendis maxime rerum natus expedita?</div>
      <div>Error delectus explicabo earum, sed eligendi autem animi quod nisi. Atque voluptatem quidem doloremque autem vero maiores fugit dolor libero animi inventore nobis nihil ex, veniam, corporis impedit nulla voluptas?</div>
      <div>Aspernatur nostrum consequatur doloribus, blanditiis odio eaque sint eius similique officiis, animi eum earum consequuntur asperiores perspiciatis quae voluptatum error ratione? Ut saepe sit cupiditate et, dicta veritatis quas ex.</div>
      <div>Vero iusto aperiam aspernatur voluptatem provident error a nulla illum minus quasi et nesciunt autem veniam tempore esse blanditiis alias illo deleniti repellat, quo ullam voluptates deserunt nemo. Minus, exercitationem.</div>
      <div>Totam officia itaque ipsum maiores expedita odio, quaerat temporibus sunt, aperiam perspiciatis. Rerum, sint, eveniet? Qui vel deserunt at ex esse quam ducimus assumenda fuga. Officia odio velit, ad laboriosam.</div>
      <div>Dignissimos numquam atque, at nobis nesciunt delectus dolores odit alias cupiditate obcaecati ex iure tempora sequi. Labore voluptas odio dolor possimus, alias placeat necessitatibus ducimus rem tempora fugiat cumque veritatis.</div>
      <div>Minima aut, suscipit officiis, veniam quidem blanditiis. Molestiae quibusdam porro numquam. Nemo esse deleniti voluptatum doloremque dicta obcaecati delectus blanditiis! Nam ab, maxime ipsum aliquid sapiente, laborum fuga consequuntur veniam.</div>
      <div>Quisquam mollitia, accusantium error recusandae modi deserunt, dolores fugit. Ipsam provident, consectetur iure dicta reprehenderit voluptates nostrum quisquam necessitatibus, tenetur, quia natus explicabo quos totam ut voluptatibus, facere quibusdam
        aperiam?
      </div>
      <div>Minima excepturi animi illo explicabo, deserunt corporis, iure consequatur sapiente natus quos aliquam consectetur similique odio laudantium beatae perspiciatis itaque cum porro exercitationem numquam quisquam totam iste in fugit nobis!</div>
      <div>Quod minima, natus similique iusto nam tempore delectus accusantium nesciunt officia, laudantium eos commodi fugit facilis voluptate magni. Impedit est tenetur ipsam quae! Quos beatae voluptate impedit laudantium, sequi assumenda?</div>
      <div>Fuga labore commodi tempora, eius quos. Qui eum, hic, cumque iure perferendis numquam ducimus incidunt dolore possimus nam necessitatibus est fuga eligendi suscipit! Repudiandae illum quam accusantium quos! Eligendi, soluta!</div>
      <div>Voluptatibus iusto veritatis repudiandae temporibus quis blanditiis. Corporis non quaerat, vel debitis minima autem nobis commodi aut sit natus. Nemo, soluta cumque assumenda adipisci! Eveniet, minima tenetur et! Temporibus, eveniet?</div>
      <div>Saepe sunt minima fugiat sit aliquid modi veritatis dolorem aut expedita eos natus vero molestiae molestias neque labore, a nobis deleniti laboriosam officiis ex dolorum. Quis, distinctio cupiditate. Fuga, voluptate.</div>
      <div>Libero ipsam numquam nesciunt at harum quis quia aliquid facilis sunt porro nobis vero voluptatibus eos pariatur ad, nam. Rerum nemo voluptas ab consequatur, debitis provident repellat illo, ratione iure.</div>
      <div>Deserunt recusandae, esse voluptates, unde minus eligendi atque eaque! Mollitia rerum animi fuga doloribus, aperiam ipsa earum voluptatum accusamus ipsum, ex saepe itaque harum inventore quo? Fugiat neque in pariatur.</div>
      <div>Id non accusamus dolores, ipsa esse dolorum facere repudiandae blanditiis accusantium veniam, autem sapiente vitae ducimus, nemo, fuga incidunt aperiam reprehenderit quaerat ex nesciunt recusandae distinctio praesentium consequatur corporis. Praesentium?</div>
      <div>Adipisci ea quos optio ab nesciunt vero delectus, beatae repellat cupiditate ad, omnis asperiores ut perferendis! Vitae, voluptatem dolores dolore sequi perspiciatis maiores eum minus molestias consequatur quaerat sint dolorem.</div>
      <div>Id nam, aut saepe, magnam ullam voluptate fugit eligendi dolorem maiores nesciunt sapiente excepturi. Similique animi hic nesciunt, minus amet at ratione, quas quisquam pariatur, voluptates dolorum blanditiis earum! Eaque.</div>
      <div>Quis corrupti nobis a vero, voluptate consectetur distinctio voluptatum veniam nihil deleniti eos architecto voluptatibus autem! Fugit culpa molestiae eaque quas tempora, dicta perspiciatis numquam et, harum ratione voluptatibus suscipit.</div>
      <div>Quo praesentium aspernatur expedita vel fugit non ut minus tempora asperiores quae quis aperiam molestias voluptates molestiae nam, eveniet perspiciatis nobis, natus. Id debitis, error ipsa tempora. Perferendis, nobis, libero.</div>
      <div>Enim, nesciunt, cupiditate! Molestias sapiente totam dolores accusamus, voluptatum, exercitationem aliquid numquam quaerat? Aliquam ducimus voluptatum repellendus nobis voluptatibus, exercitationem, saepe, sequi adipisci quia quam tempore. Nam fugit
        voluptate non.</div>
      <div>Officiis porro, corporis rerum voluptas labore sapiente vero sed non id, inventore ad, quas molestiae nobis, doloribus illum distinctio consequuntur quisquam possimus! Consequatur quas rem suscipit libero vero. Asperiores, velit.</div>
      <div>Eos molestiae sint unde minima enim iste voluptatibus nemo ipsum reiciendis aspernatur provident, repellendus vitae nesciunt a asperiores placeat omnis nam nisi cum fuga ipsa necessitatibus expedita eveniet accusantium? Saepe.</div>
      <div>Numquam temporibus harum autem ipsa. Facere quos, maxime aliquid ducimus et nesciunt porro vel beatae ab exercitationem. Rem tempore culpa est minima numquam voluptatum, neque et adipisci non iusto recusandae!</div>
      <div>Porro nemo ipsum, consequuntur cum possimus itaque aut voluptatibus laborum at modi magnam, excepturi fugit minima reprehenderit vitae aliquid quis facilis assumenda expedita tempora voluptatem quo doloribus dolorum asperiores. Hic.</div>
      <div>Neque impedit maiores autem itaque temporibus nulla enim id, illum, quisquam excepturi repellendus. Culpa, impedit, ex amet ab velit voluptatem eum dicta repudiandae beatae similique ut optio? Fugiat, pariatur, dignissimos.</div>
      <div>Impedit omnis unde provident repellendus voluptatum aspernatur dolores maxime expedita repellat excepturi ratione, asperiores aut voluptatem nam iure officia enim veniam porro, cupiditate voluptate veritatis temporibus, est mollitia ipsa. Sapiente.</div>
      <div>Odio impedit dolores quidem facere, vel, ad eveniet similique dicta aliquam in ex cumque, temporibus quaerat. Repudiandae nihil itaque officiis necessitatibus, dolorem alias, ratione voluptates soluta in, blanditiis ipsum natus.</div>
      <div>Iure mollitia suscipit unde repellat. Quisquam cum in officia fugiat ipsam quidem consequuntur voluptates itaque dignissimos sequi nisi inventore id, magni provident, error soluta, animi tempore aliquid! Itaque, odit, debitis.</div>
      <div>Dolore a nihil nostrum quasi, esse quos alias dolor earum nesciunt necessitatibus atque, rerum tempora, sint, repellat sed nam dolorem distinctio eius sunt porro amet. Explicabo necessitatibus ducimus delectus consequuntur.</div>
      <div>Tenetur vero, atque numquam debitis sit minus perspiciatis doloremque! Quaerat praesentium eum, aut, cumque itaque deleniti sit sequi, incidunt ipsum, ipsa error non ratione eius quidem minus vel illum laudantium.</div>
      <div>Quam architecto laboriosam at officiis repudiandae illo magnam qui reiciendis dolore accusantium recusandae, amet itaque magni cupiditate in dolorem ad voluptate, est labore explicabo neque. Porro dolorem quas, deleniti autem?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/rf150rus/pen/PjZRNz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  display: table
}

.col-xs-6 {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none !important;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 23px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

li {
  background: blue;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
}

li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: -20px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="bg">
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
          <li>Cum, corporis.</li>
          <li>Illum, ad.</li>
          <li>Eaque, consectetur.</li>
          <li>Culpa, a.</li>
          <li>Nulla, aliquid?</li>
          <li>Est, velit?</li>
          <li>Unde, autem.</li>
          <li>Ullam, ad!</li>
          <li>A, harum.</li>
          <li>Esse, dolores.</li>
          <li>Tempore, adipisci.</li>
          <li>Maiores, voluptatum.</li>
          <li>Nisi, iusto.</li>
          <li>Numquam, totam!</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum ipsum odio nesciunt, pariatur aliquid laudantium consequatur odit ducimus tenetur soluta dolores harum mollitia eaque tempore blanditiis facere eveniet neque distinctio.</div>
      <div>Quia architecto laborum excepturi reiciendis vero, ab amet, voluptatibus molestiae sit earum exercitationem minima vitae! Debitis dolorem praesentium cum nam similique architecto illum magnam labore rerum assumenda soluta, unde quas.</div>
      <div>Tempore, veritatis. Sunt, accusantium, culpa quibusdam, eius enim molestiae hic blanditiis perferendis necessitatibus pariatur fugit! Inventore ad labore quae, minima cupiditate temporibus quia, debitis delectus repellat, voluptatibus reprehenderit
        laboriosam facere.</div>
      <div>Itaque molestias, quisquam ex fugiat aperiam porro sit repudiandae accusamus quod eligendi reprehenderit. Quas expedita libero quos iusto excepturi ipsum adipisci voluptatem incidunt cumque. Optio ab perspiciatis deleniti consectetur, quis?</div>
      <div>Voluptatum, quia numquam rerum saepe maxime! Quibusdam harum eveniet beatae fuga a, maxime eum sint dolorum rerum corporis qui distinctio necessitatibus cumque facilis inventore impedit totam minus temporibus officia voluptatibus.</div>
      <div>Incidunt rerum alias iusto temporibus amet illum quia aspernatur quaerat nemo veniam ipsam, natus ullam qui. Quibusdam accusantium, in explicabo nam consectetur blanditiis assumenda, facere, nobis deserunt ex omnis distinctio?</div>
      <div>Harum asperiores dolores, optio quasi hic facere quibusdam excepturi sint, natus tempore iure adipisci ab. Iste aperiam libero voluptatum, ab eos a, minus aspernatur deserunt, deleniti sunt magni in alias.</div>
      <div>Iusto fuga reprehenderit quae nihil, distinctio quam rerum tempore rem enim assumenda harum nisi consectetur, non aut nesciunt explicabo nam, architecto, nobis perferendis culpa magnam? Dolorem sequi quod, temporibus tempora.</div>
      <div>Sapiente, esse adipisci voluptates non porro dolorum libero dolores, ipsam consequuntur quaerat ea optio illum sint, dignissimos sunt soluta. Accusantium consequatur, minima modi quasi quaerat reiciendis maxime rerum natus expedita?</div>
      <div>Error delectus explicabo earum, sed eligendi autem animi quod nisi. Atque voluptatem quidem doloremque autem vero maiores fugit dolor libero animi inventore nobis nihil ex, veniam, corporis impedit nulla voluptas?</div>
      <div>Aspernatur nostrum consequatur doloribus, blanditiis odio eaque sint eius similique officiis, animi eum earum consequuntur asperiores perspiciatis quae voluptatum error ratione? Ut saepe sit cupiditate et, dicta veritatis quas ex.</div>
      <div>Vero iusto aperiam aspernatur voluptatem provident error a nulla illum minus quasi et nesciunt autem veniam tempore esse blanditiis alias illo deleniti repellat, quo ullam voluptates deserunt nemo. Minus, exercitationem.</div>
      <div>Totam officia itaque ipsum maiores expedita odio, quaerat temporibus sunt, aperiam perspiciatis. Rerum, sint, eveniet? Qui vel deserunt at ex esse quam ducimus assumenda fuga. Officia odio velit, ad laboriosam.</div>
      <div>Dignissimos numquam atque, at nobis nesciunt delectus dolores odit alias cupiditate obcaecati ex iure tempora sequi. Labore voluptas odio dolor possimus, alias placeat necessitatibus ducimus rem tempora fugiat cumque veritatis.</div>
      <div>Minima aut, suscipit officiis, veniam quidem blanditiis. Molestiae quibusdam porro numquam. Nemo esse deleniti voluptatum doloremque dicta obcaecati delectus blanditiis! Nam ab, maxime ipsum aliquid sapiente, laborum fuga consequuntur veniam.</div>
      <div>Quisquam mollitia, accusantium error recusandae modi deserunt, dolores fugit. Ipsam provident, consectetur iure dicta reprehenderit voluptates nostrum quisquam necessitatibus, tenetur, quia natus explicabo quos totam ut voluptatibus, facere quibusdam
        aperiam?
      </div>
      <div>Minima excepturi animi illo explicabo, deserunt corporis, iure consequatur sapiente natus quos aliquam consectetur similique odio laudantium beatae perspiciatis itaque cum porro exercitationem numquam quisquam totam iste in fugit nobis!</div>
      <div>Quod minima, natus similique iusto nam tempore delectus accusantium nesciunt officia, laudantium eos commodi fugit facilis voluptate magni. Impedit est tenetur ipsam quae! Quos beatae voluptate impedit laudantium, sequi assumenda?</div>
      <div>Fuga labore commodi tempora, eius quos. Qui eum, hic, cumque iure perferendis numquam ducimus incidunt dolore possimus nam necessitatibus est fuga eligendi suscipit! Repudiandae illum quam accusantium quos! Eligendi, soluta!</div>
      <div>Voluptatibus iusto veritatis repudiandae temporibus quis blanditiis. Corporis non quaerat, vel debitis minima autem nobis commodi aut sit natus. Nemo, soluta cumque assumenda adipisci! Eveniet, minima tenetur et! Temporibus, eveniet?</div>
      <div>Saepe sunt minima fugiat sit aliquid modi veritatis dolorem aut expedita eos natus vero molestiae molestias neque labore, a nobis deleniti laboriosam officiis ex dolorum. Quis, distinctio cupiditate. Fuga, voluptate.</div>
      <div>Libero ipsam numquam nesciunt at harum quis quia aliquid facilis sunt porro nobis vero voluptatibus eos pariatur ad, nam. Rerum nemo voluptas ab consequatur, debitis provident repellat illo, ratione iure.</div>
      <div>Deserunt recusandae, esse voluptates, unde minus eligendi atque eaque! Mollitia rerum animi fuga doloribus, aperiam ipsa earum voluptatum accusamus ipsum, ex saepe itaque harum inventore quo? Fugiat neque in pariatur.</div>
      <div>Id non accusamus dolores, ipsa esse dolorum facere repudiandae blanditiis accusantium veniam, autem sapiente vitae ducimus, nemo, fuga incidunt aperiam reprehenderit quaerat ex nesciunt recusandae distinctio praesentium consequatur corporis. Praesentium?</div>
      <div>Adipisci ea quos optio ab nesciunt vero delectus, beatae repellat cupiditate ad, omnis asperiores ut perferendis! Vitae, voluptatem dolores dolore sequi perspiciatis maiores eum minus molestias consequatur quaerat sint dolorem.</div>
      <div>Id nam, aut saepe, magnam ullam voluptate fugit eligendi dolorem maiores nesciunt sapiente excepturi. Similique animi hic nesciunt, minus amet at ratione, quas quisquam pariatur, voluptates dolorum blanditiis earum! Eaque.</div>
      <div>Quis corrupti nobis a vero, voluptate consectetur distinctio voluptatum veniam nihil deleniti eos architecto voluptatibus autem! Fugit culpa molestiae eaque quas tempora, dicta perspiciatis numquam et, harum ratione voluptatibus suscipit.</div>
      <div>Quo praesentium aspernatur expedita vel fugit non ut minus tempora asperiores quae quis aperiam molestias voluptates molestiae nam, eveniet perspiciatis nobis, natus. Id debitis, error ipsa tempora. Perferendis, nobis, libero.</div>
      <div>Enim, nesciunt, cupiditate! Molestias sapiente totam dolores accusamus, voluptatum, exercitationem aliquid numquam quaerat? Aliquam ducimus voluptatum repellendus nobis voluptatibus, exercitationem, saepe, sequi adipisci quia quam tempore. Nam fugit
        voluptate non.</div>
      <div>Officiis porro, corporis rerum voluptas labore sapiente vero sed non id, inventore ad, quas molestiae nobis, doloribus illum distinctio consequuntur quisquam possimus! Consequatur quas rem suscipit libero vero. Asperiores, velit.</div>
      <div>Eos molestiae sint unde minima enim iste voluptatibus nemo ipsum reiciendis aspernatur provident, repellendus vitae nesciunt a asperiores placeat omnis nam nisi cum fuga ipsa necessitatibus expedita eveniet accusantium? Saepe.</div>
      <div>Numquam temporibus harum autem ipsa. Facere quos, maxime aliquid ducimus et nesciunt porro vel beatae ab exercitationem. Rem tempore culpa est minima numquam voluptatum, neque et adipisci non iusto recusandae!</div>
      <div>Porro nemo ipsum, consequuntur cum possimus itaque aut voluptatibus laborum at modi magnam, excepturi fugit minima reprehenderit vitae aliquid quis facilis assumenda expedita tempora voluptatem quo doloribus dolorum asperiores. Hic.</div>
      <div>Neque impedit maiores autem itaque temporibus nulla enim id, illum, quisquam excepturi repellendus. Culpa, impedit, ex amet ab velit voluptatem eum dicta repudiandae beatae similique ut optio? Fugiat, pariatur, dignissimos.</div>
      <div>Impedit omnis unde provident repellendus voluptatum aspernatur dolores maxime expedita repellat excepturi ratione, asperiores aut voluptatem nam iure officia enim veniam porro, cupiditate voluptate veritatis temporibus, est mollitia ipsa. Sapiente.</div>
      <div>Odio impedit dolores quidem facere, vel, ad eveniet similique dicta aliquam in ex cumque, temporibus quaerat. Repudiandae nihil itaque officiis necessitatibus, dolorem alias, ratione voluptates soluta in, blanditiis ipsum natus.</div>
      <div>Iure mollitia suscipit unde repellat. Quisquam cum in officia fugiat ipsam quidem consequuntur voluptates itaque dignissimos sequi nisi inventore id, magni provident, error soluta, animi tempore aliquid! Itaque, odit, debitis.</div>
      <div>Dolore a nihil nostrum quasi, esse quos alias dolor earum nesciunt necessitatibus atque, rerum tempora, sint, repellat sed nam dolorem distinctio eius sunt porro amet. Explicabo necessitatibus ducimus delectus consequuntur.</div>
      <div>Tenetur vero, atque numquam debitis sit minus perspiciatis doloremque! Quaerat praesentium eum, aut, cumque itaque deleniti sit sequi, incidunt ipsum, ipsa error non ratione eius quidem minus vel illum laudantium.</div>
      <div>Quam architecto laboriosam at officiis repudiandae illo magnam qui reiciendis dolore accusantium recusandae, amet itaque magni cupiditate in dolorem ad voluptate, est labore explicabo neque. Porro dolorem quas, deleniti autem?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не, не то... Смысл в том, что стрелки должны быть с эфектом, как будто они на блоке с контентом.

Comment: @sepgg отредактировал

Comment: Спасибо за пинок в нужную сторону, немного доработал, получилось то , что нужно)